# Webbrowser where I can login to access history etc

Tags: browser, sync, cloud

Is there any webbrowser where everything, like history, bookmarks, download history and preferences on the cloud so that is possible to login to any of that webbrowser and it will be exactly the same on whatever computer you use?

Something like chrome's sync except that with that, you can't go to any computer with chrome on it and just click login and enter your google account and without messing anything up (like resetting the sync settings) make it look like your own browser at home.

Effectively a cloud browser rather than Sync.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Firefox Sync!

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10868/

Comment: but will that mean that if I go to any firefox browser with sync installed I can access my bookmarks etc without messing the local stuff already there.

Comment: no you will have to make sure the firefox sync addon is installed on that computer.

Comment: yes I know, but will it remove any local things, and I don't want it to sync my friends history and bookmarks with my sync account.

Comment: But I thought you said you "wanted it to look like your own browser at home".  If you just want to access web history or bookmarks, you could use Google Web History or Xmarks, but I don't understand why you'd want to store your browser preferences in the cloud if you weren't planning on pulling them back down to install them locally on another machine.  And I also don't know (short of Firefox Sync) how you'd save download history in the cloud.

Comment: What I mean is that I don't want to sync my stuff from the cloud. Syncing means it copys it to the local computer. I want to just access it so that it is temporary. See if I go to a friends house with the right software/addons installed I only want to view my bookmarks/history not download them onto his computer so that when I log off my sync account everything returns to how it was and you'd never know that I'd been there.

Comment: Well, Xmarks and Google Web History let you see your bookmarks and web history online without synching them down to the local machine (with Xmarks, though, you'd use the Xmarks extension on your home computer but browse your account on xmarks.com to see your bookmarks whilst at a friend's house).  Also, I know this solution is in a little different direction, but you could consider keeping around a copy of Portable Firefox (either on a flash drive or zipped up in the cloud, like in Dropbox).